# how to compute GPU's max. num. of threads programmatically

Tags: cuda

Can you show how to compute maximum number of threads that can reside in specific GPU using CUDA? I.e. maximum number of threads that I can assign to kernel. Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a kernel query of some sort.  You could always assume a power of 2, start with 4, then double until you stop getting gains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the maximum number of threads per multiprocessor (SM) using [`cudaGetDeviceProperties()`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html). Then multiply this by the number of SMs in your card.

Though this does not necessarily mean you should execute this number of threads. Consult this SO answer for [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565637/811001).

Comment: thanks, so is it ="maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor"*"multiProcessorCount"?

Comment: can you show example on this values "http://idius.net/wp-content/uploads/text-files/deviceQuery.txt" for GTX 580, i am asking this because here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490572/cuda-how-many-concurrent-threads-in-total" it is shown to be 24,576 threads for GTX 580. thanks!

Comment: The GTX580 is a Fermi part with 16 SMs. Each SM can run up to 1536 threads simultaneously. 16 x 1536 = 24,576 threads for the entire GPU. Note that maximum number of threads per multiprocessor (1536) is different from maximum number of threads per thread block / CTA (1024).

Comment: So, does this mean that Tesla C2050 will have 14*1536=21504 threads for the entire GPU?

Comment: Correct, the C2050 has 14 SMs with up to 1536 concurrently running threads each, for a total of up to 21,504 concurrently running threads across the entire GPU.